# I want to make dsnless connection of ms access with java on 64 bit machione

Tags: java, database, ms-access, connection, 64-bit

I want to make dsnless connection of ms access with java on a 64 bit machine. I was using the following code on 32 bit:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection MSA_con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=C:\\data\\data.mdb");
```

and this code is working only on 32 bit machine, now i am shifted to 64 bit machine here this code is giving following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I have done lots of RND for all this, but couldn't fix it. For an 64 bit machine I do not know where to get a 64 bit ODBC driver and how to install it on my machine. Do I have to use jdk 64 bit or do I have to install microsoft ace drivers or should I just use some other connection string?
My machine is 64 bit window 7 ultimate, ms access 2007, jdk 32 bit.

Comment: If your Java application really is running under a 32-bit JVM on your 64-bit Windows machine then your existing connection string should work. Have your Java application show you the value returned by `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` to verify.

Comment: Your other comment said that `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` was "not returning anything". My understanding is that it *must* return something, either `32` or `64` depending on whether the application that calls it is running under a 32-bit or a 64-bit JVM. Try again.

Comment: yeah its returning 64.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application calls `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` and it returns `64` then your application is running under a 64-bit JVM. In that case the connection string you quoted in your question won't work because there is no 64-bit version of the older Microsoft Jet ODBC driver. You also cannot download and install the 64-bit version of the newer Access Database Engine (ACE) driver because you already have the 32-bit version on your machine. You will need to configure your application to run under a 32-bit JVM.